# CSS constants library support

Tags: css, tomcat

CSS doesn't support constants, particularly for colors, which makes css color maintenance a real pain.

Before I roll my own solution, are there any good libraries that work with tomcat that support the concept of CSS constants?

Comment: Have you tried SASS? Looks like there is an apache module for it: http://mdavidgreen.com/blog/making-apache-serve-haml-and-sass-pages-dynamically/

Comment: @itadapter - Do you mean [`less`](http://lesscss.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main options:

Newest is actual variables in the browser - http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/ though support is (currently) poor.  Will probably improve through 2013.

Mainstream is "Sass" - http://sass-lang.com/ -  "Sass makes CSS fun again. Sass is an extension of CSS3, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool or a web-framework plugin."

Sass variable: `$blue: #3bbfce;`

Also, very popular, "LESS" - http://lesscss.org/ - "LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions. 
 LESS runs on both the server-side (with Node.js and Rhino) or client-side (modern browsers only)."

LESS variable: `@color: #4D926F;`

Both Sass and Less compile into css.